# Managing MVC checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have these two related check boxes:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("Issue", new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-align-center padding-top-7">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IssueDisplay)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-align-center padding-top-7">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IssueRequired, new { @onclick = "SetDisplayCheckbox(this,'IssueDisplay');" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript for `SetDisplayCheckbox()` looks like this:

```
SetDisplayCheckbox = function (reqCb, targetCb) {
    debugger;
    var displayCb;
    if (targetCb == null || targetCb == undefined) {
        displayCb = $(reqCb).closest('.displayRequired').find('.requireMe')[0];
    }
    else
    {
        displayCb = $(document.getElementById(targetCb))[0];
    }
    if (reqCb.checked == true) {
        displayCb.checked = true;
        displayCb.disabled = true;
        displayCb.value = true; // I've tried with and without this.
    } else {
        displayCb.disabled = false;
    }
};
```

The javascript works well, checking the `IssueDisplay` checkbox, except when I submit the form, the `IssueDisplay` value comes back as false.

Why doesn't the checkbox get set to true, when checked is true?

Answer (score 1):

Disabled fields in form are not posted to the server, so your value is always going to be false. Try remove this line

```
displayCb.disabled = true;
```

If you still need the checkbox to be disabled, you could probably enable it just before the form's submit event.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the `value` attribute of the `IssueDisplay` checkbox to `"True"`.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IssueDisplay, new { value = "True" })
```

Comment: `@CheckBoxFor()` generates 2 inputs - a checkbox with `value="True"` and a hidden input with `value="False". You never set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` (and in this case its pointless since the value is already "True"